# What is the mathematical notation of the second and the third lowest values of a variable X?

Tags: notation

Assume the time series $\{X_t\}_{t=1}^{260}$ with elements $X_t \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is the mathematical notation of the second and the third lowest values from that time series?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thanks.